# C# render textfield characters as password dots

Tags: c#, ext.net

I am using `Ext-Net` framework where there is not autocomplete property for a textfield.

So I have a textfield with the property `InputType="Password"` so it is recognized as password field from `Chrome` and it is autocompleted. If I remove the `InputType` property then the characters are not masked.

How I can mask the characters as password dots if I remove the `InputType` property?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean autocompletion as in the field's contents being cached, or autocompletion as being filled in by a password manager?

If the latter, this is actually good because it makes it easier for users to use a password manager to generate and use random and unique passwords (which is excellent security practice) and reduces the temptation for users to reuse passwords (which is poor security practice), so my recommendation would thus be to **not** inhibit this autocompletion.

Comment: The problem is that its a very sensitive application and the password is used as signature. So we have to be certain that there is no possibility that someone else is using the application and the password is autocompleted.

Comment: @aggicd This does not change my answer, nor the recommendations therein. Also, passwords ≠ signatures.

Comment: thank you for your recommendations but what about the implementation ? any thoughts?